# How to combine entries from two NSMutableDictionary objects?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsmutabledictionary

i try and combine my dictionaries but to be honest i have no idea how. i try like thus, but two overtake one. sorry for the bad english.

```
[dict addEntriesFromDictionary:dict2];
```

1

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Main</key>
    <dict>
        <key>DataStorage1</key>
        <dict>
            <key>A</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>B</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>C</key>
            <string></string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

2

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Main</key>
    <dict>
        <key>DataStorage2</key>
        <dict>
            <key>A</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>B</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>C</key>
            <string></string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I would like to make:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Main</key>
    <dict>
        <key>DataStorage1</key>
        <dict>
            <key>A</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>B</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>C</key>
            <string></string>
        </dict>
        <key>DataStorage2</key>
        <dict>
            <key>A</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>B</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>C</key>
            <string></string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

I tried, but it never combined correctly.

Comment: This is the right code. Make sure that the two dictionaries that you are combining do not share entries.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, do you mean such as "Main"? if so how can i put them both in "Main". thanks you

Answer (score 3):

Both `dict` and `dict2` have one one key-value pair with the common key "Main".
Therefore

```
[dict addEntriesFromDictionary:dict2];
```

*replaces* the entire "Main" dictionary in `dict` with the value from `dict2`.

What you probably want is

```
[dict[@"Main"] addEntriesFromDictionary:dict2[@"Main"]];
```

to add the key-values pairs from the "Main" dictionary in `dict2` to the "Main"
dictionary in `dict`. (This assumes that the "Main" dictionary in `dict`
is *mutable*.)

---

Example:

```
NSURL *url1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"plist1" withExtension:@"plist"];
NSURL *url2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"plist2" withExtension:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *dict1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:url1];
NSMutableDictionary *dict2 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:url2];

[dict1[@"Main"] addEntriesFromDictionary:dict2[@"Main"]];
```

Comment: @user3625517: That would mean that dict or dict2 is an array and not a dictionary. - I have tested the code with your data and it worked for me. I have added a full working example to the answer, perhaps that helps.

Comment: hi - heres my code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/816bb587194287155a8f . i only get dict2 :(

Comment: I have tested your code from https://gist.github.com/anonymous/816bb587194287155a8f. After replacing stringByAppendingString with stringByAppendingPathComponent it worked as expected with your plists. - The problem with ideone is that is uses a compiler that does not know the NSDictionary "subscripting" syntax `dict1[@"Main"]`.

Comment: hi martin yes i noticed the path component also, but did you get both dictionaries to show up under Main? i dict2 overwrite dict1 when i run it. the error on ideone i got also in Xcode, but only with first time. thank again (here is output i get: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b3a34b743c71e72ff856)

Comment: i not understand why dict2 overwrtie dict1 everytime.

Comment: @user3625517: I have tested exactly your code with your plists, and dict2 did not overwrite dict1.

Comment: any idea why mine get overwritten? it really strange this. :(

Comment: is subscript syntax limitee to ARC?

Comment: @user3625517: I don't think so.